# Can I create a desktop shortcut to a website without going through the browser?

Tags: shortcut, desktop, url

I'd like to add a desktop shortcut to a URL that will show up on the desktop for all users of the Mac. The only methods I've found for creating one involves navigating to the desired website in a browser, then dragging from the address bar to the desktop. But the URL I want to use is one that, upon navigating to it, will automatically close the browser tab and launch the appropriate desktop app instead. So I have no way to get a browser tab "open" to the necessary URL in order to be able to drag it out of the browser window.

On Windows PCs, I know that I can right-click on the desktop, and choose "New Shortcut", then type a URL and it will make an "Internet shortcut". Is there a way to do this on a Mac?

Comment: Try manually creating a bookmark in your browser of choice (I tested in Firefox), then drag it to your desktop.  It worked a treat.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Can you share the link and the application name that will be used to handle the link?

Comment: @Nimesh It's a Zoom meeting link.

Comment: @Allan good idea, I'll try that. You should submit it as an answer, though!

Comment: @Allan this worked. Please convert your comment into an answer so that I can accept it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you manually create/edit a bookmark in the browser of your choice (tested in Safari, Edge and Firefox), you can then “click and drag” that bookmark to your Desktop.